# Windows server path

Tags: path, windows-server

Sorry for this simple question, I know I can have a try on windows system but I don't have windows server on my access.
Windows server path starts with this kind of slash "//" or "\\" , say

```
//servername/mypath  or \\servername\mypath
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the question here?  As written, this is a statement, not a question.  It's also, contrary to the below, a true statement (after of course substituting "UNC name" for "server path").  (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the backslash variety:

```
\\servername\path
```